# IRI validation, unexpected fail with encoded <> symbols

Tags: debugging, internationalization, url-encoding, apache-abdera, iri

I'm working with abdera in my project and it fails during parsing IRI address from content which contains already encoded < and > symbols: `&gt; &lt;`
The exception is: "org.apache.abdera.i18n.text.InvalidCharacterException: Invalid Character 0x3c(<)"

I'm confused since as I know these symbols (`&gt; &lt;`) are allowed in IRI format.

Could you please advise

EDIT:
I'm using getHref() method of class org.apache.abdera.model.Link and the link is something like: `http://blabla.com?xxx&gt;yyy&lt;zzz`

Comment: Could you possibly include a code snippit showing what you are attempting?

Comment: I've updated the question, please take a look

Comment: Have you tried escaping the `<` and `>` symbols? i.e. `http://blabla.com?xxx\>yyy\<zzz`. You may need to backslash characters for each; Java's a bit pedantic with escaping.

Answer (score 0):

It's parsing the symbol as an XML entity, so there are two solutions:

- URI Encode the IRI within `getHref`

  ```
  encode("http://blabla.com?xxx&gt;yyy&lt;zzz", "utf-8")
  ```
- Use another method rather than `getHref`

**References**

- [XPath and XQuery Functions 3.1: iri-to-uri](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-iri-to-uri)